# An invalid domain.test.com was specified for this cookie

Tags: java, cookies

Why am I not able to set wildcard domain cookie in java?

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("id", "c");
cookie.setDomain(".test.com");
response.addCookie(cookie);
response.sendRedirect(redirect);
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
```

An invalid domain [.test.com] was specified for this cookie

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's correct per [RFC 2109](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109). What's the **exact** error message and its stack trace?

Comment: :-) I'm not sure what I should repost. My original answer was definitely wrong. It may be best just to delete the question...?